# Javascript: event duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, asynchronous

I can not figure out what is wrong with my code.
I have a couple of global variables which I change every time some certain button is pressed,there is also a couple of custom functions that perform ajax calls that returns a chunk of html code with a pagination below, that works like this:

```
    $('#foot #pagination a.page').live('click', function(){
        window.mode = 'partial';        
        window.key = $('input#search').val();           
        window.page = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
        setTimeout('getData();', 0);        
    });
```

sometimes when moving to another page event doubles and I got the doubled html.
when caling getData(); from a browser console - everything works fine, like it has to work.
What can cause this?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that jQuery `.live()` pushes some data to jQuery stack on document ready, but after ajax response comes from the server and document ready event is called again - in this case `.live()` pushes the same data again to a jQuery stack, which then causes multiple event body calls.

I used `.die()` before `.live()` and everything now works fine.

Comment: "after ajax response comes from the server and document ready event is called again" -- **no**, `document.ready` is not called again on an ajax response. Do you happen to be calling `.live` again from `getData`, or from any other function it calls?

Comment: yes, DOM.ready loads a new bunch of event handlers where .live loads again, you are right, actually this was an error behavour.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute this function only once after `document.ready`.
Or do something like this:

```
$('#foot').off('click', '#pagination a.page', navigation) // remove event
          .on('click', '#pagination a.page', navigation); // add event

function navigation(e) {
   window.mode = 'partial';        
   window.key = $('input#search').val();           
   window.page = $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('input').val();
   setTimeout('getData();', 0);        
});
```